# AWS Billing dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, billing, aws-billing

I want to give an IAM user permissions so that he can only view the Cost Management section and he shouldnt be able to see anything else.
OR
I want to give the IAM user permission so that he can only view the cost and usage reports and he shouldnt be able to see anything else

Comment: Those are 2 different services - S3 for CUR and Billing for CE

Answer (score 0):

Read the official documentation. Attach the following policy to your specific IAM user, something like this:

```
{Effect: Allow, Action: Billing:Read}
```